# While creating new account screen keeps spinning in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm new to flutter and I have created an application with login/signup screens and connected my app to fire base, it's successfully connected but when signup or login it keeps spinning. However, I can see in firebase user is added but it doesn't get access to application home screen.

Here is my dart code for sign up:

```dart
    import 'dart:io';

    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_login_screen/model/User.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_login_screen/ui/home/HomeScreen.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_login_screen/ui/services/Authenticate.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_login_screen/ui/utils/helper.dart';
    import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

    import '../../constants.dart' as Constants;
    import '../../constants.dart';
    import '../../main.dart';

    File _image;

    class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State createState() => _SignUpState();
    }

    class _SignUpState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
      TextEditingController _passwordController = new TextEditingController();
      GlobalKey<FormState> _key = new GlobalKey();
      bool _validate = false;
      String firstName, lastName, email, mobile, password, confirmPassword;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          retrieveLostData();
        }

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16, bottom: 16),
              child: new Form(
                key: _key,
                autovalidate: _validate,
                child: formUI(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

      Future<void> retrieveLostData() async {
        final LostDataResponse response = await ImagePicker.retrieveLostData();
        if (response == null) {
          return;
        }
        if (response.file != null) {
          setState(() {
            _image = response.file;
          });
        }
      }

      _onCameraClick() {
        final action = CupertinoActionSheet(
          message: Text(
            "Add profile picture",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            CupertinoActionSheetAction(
              child: Text("Choose from gallery"),
              isDefaultAction: false,
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                var image =
                    await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                setState(() {
                  _image = image;
                });
              },
            ),
            CupertinoActionSheetAction(
              child: Text("Take a picture"),
              isDestructiveAction: false,
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
                setState(() {
                  _image = image;
                });
              },
            )
          ],
          cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
            child: Text("Cancel"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        );
        showCupertinoModalPopup(context: context, builder: (context) => action);
      }

      Widget formUI() {
        return new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(
                  'Create new account',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 25.0),
                )),
            Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top: 32, right: 8, bottom: 8),
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 65,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
                    child: ClipOval(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 170,
                        height: 170,
                        child: _image == null
                            ? Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/placeholder.jpg',
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              )
                            : Image.file(
                                _image,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    left: 80,
                    right: 0,
                    child: FloatingActionButton(
                        backgroundColor: Color(COLOR_ACCENT),
                        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                        mini: true,
                        onPressed: _onCameraClick),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
                child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, right: 8.0, left: 8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                        validator: validateName,
                        onSaved: (String val) {
                          firstName = val;
                        },
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        onFieldSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            hintText: 'First Name',
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                                    width: 2.0)),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            ))))),
            ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
                child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, right: 8.0, left: 8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                        validator: validateName,
                        onSaved: (String val) {
                          lastName = val;
                        },
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        onFieldSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            hintText: 'Last Name',
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                                    width: 2.0)),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            ))))),
            ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
                child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, right: 8.0, left: 8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        onFieldSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
                        validator: validateMobile,
                        onSaved: (String val) {
                          mobile = val;
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            hintText: 'Mobile Number',
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                                    width: 2.0)),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            ))))),
            ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
                child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, right: 8.0, left: 8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        onFieldSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
                        validator: validateEmail,
                        onSaved: (String val) {
                          email = val;
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            hintText: 'Email Address',
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                                    width: 2.0)),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            ))))),
            ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, right: 8.0, left: 8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                      obscureText: true,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      onFieldSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
                      controller: _passwordController,
                      validator: validatePassword,
                      onSaved: (String val) {
                        password = val;
                      },
                      style: TextStyle(height: 0.8, fontSize: 18.0),
                      cursorColor: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding:
                              new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          hintText: 'Password',
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                                  width: 2.0)),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          ))),
                )),
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, right: 8.0, left: 8.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                      _sendToServer();
                    },
                    obscureText: true,
                    validator: (val) =>
                        validateConfirmPassword(_passwordController.text, val),
                    onSaved: (String val) {
                      confirmPassword = val;
                    },
                    style: TextStyle(height: 0.8, fontSize: 18.0),
                    cursorColor: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding:
                            new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        hintText: 'Confirm Password',
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.deepOrange[900], width: 2.0)),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                        ))),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40.0, left: 40.0, top: 40.0),
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Color(Constants.FACEBOOK_BUTTON_COLOR),
                  child: Text(
                    'Sign Up',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  splashColor: Color(Constants.FACEBOOK_BUTTON_COLOR),
                  onPressed: _sendToServer,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 12),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                      side: BorderSide(
                          color: Color(Constants.FACEBOOK_BUTTON_COLOR))),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }

      _sendToServer() async {
        if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
          _key.currentState.save();
          showProgress(context, 'Creating new account...', false);
          var profilePicUrl = '';
          try {
            AuthResult result = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
            if (_image != null) {
              updateProgress('Uploading image...');
              profilePicUrl = await FireStoreUtils()
                  .uploadUserImageToFireStorage(_image, result.user.uid);
            }
            User user = User(
                email: email,
                firstName: firstName,
                phoneNumber: mobile,
                userID: result.user.uid,
                active: true,
                lastName: lastName,
                settings: Settings(allowPushNotifications: true),
                profilePictureURL: profilePicUrl);
            await FireStoreUtils.firestore
                .collection(Constants.USERS)
                .document(result.user.uid)
                .setData(user.toJson());
            hideProgress();
            MyAppState.currentUser = user;
            pushAndRemoveUntil(context, HomeScreen(user: user), false);
          } catch (error) {
            hideProgress();
            (error as PlatformException).code != 'ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE'
                ? showAlertDialog(context, 'Failed', 'Couldn\'t sign up')
                : showAlertDialog(context, 'Failed',
                    'Email already in use. Please pick another email address');
            print(error.toString());
          }
        } else {
          print('false');
          setState(() {
            _validate = true;
          });
        }
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        _passwordController.dispose();
        _image = null;
        super.dispose();
      }
    }

helper: 



import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:progress_dialog/progress_dialog.dart';



String validateName(String value) {
  String pattern = r'(^[a-zA-Z ]*$)';
  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
  if (value.length == 0) {
    return "Name is required";
  } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
    return "Name must be a-z and A-Z";
  }
  return null;
}

String validateMobile(String value) {
  String pattern = r'(^[0-9]*$)';
  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
  if (value.length == 0) {
    return "Mobile phone number is required";
  } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
    return "Mobile phone number must contain only digits";
  }
  return null;
}

String validatePassword(String value) {
  if (value.length < 6)
    return 'Password must be more than 5 charaters';
  else
    return null;
}

String validateEmail(String value) {
  Pattern pattern =
      r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
  RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
  if (!regex.hasMatch(value))
    return 'Enter Valid Email';
  else
    return null;
}

String validateConfirmPassword(String password, String confirmPassword) {
  print("$password $confirmPassword");
  if (password != confirmPassword) {
    return 'Password doesn\'t match';
  } else if (confirmPassword.length == 0) {
    return 'Confirm password is required';
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

//helper method to show progress
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

showProgress(BuildContext context, String message, bool isDismissible) async {
  progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context,
      type: ProgressDialogType.Normal, isDismissible: isDismissible);
  progressDialog.style(
      message: message,
      borderRadius: 10.0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange[900],
      progressWidget: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          )),
      elevation: 10.0,
      insetAnimCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
      messageTextStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 19.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600));
  await progressDialog.show();
}

updateProgress(String message) {
  progressDialog.update(message: message);
}

hideProgress() async {
  await progressDialog.hide();
}

//helper method to show alert dialog
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context, String title, String content) {
  // set up the AlertDialog
  Widget okButton = FlatButton(
    child: Text("OK"),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    },
  );
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text(title),
    content: Text(content),
    actions: [
      okButton,
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}

pushReplacement(BuildContext context, Widget destination) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => destination));
}

push(BuildContext context, Widget destination) {
  Navigator.of(context)
      .push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => destination));
}

pushAndRemoveUntil(BuildContext context, Widget destination, bool predict) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => destination),
      (Route<dynamic> route) => predict);
}

Widget displayCircleImage(String picUrl, double size, hasBorder) =>
    CachedNetworkImage(
        imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) =>
            _getCircularImageProvider(imageProvider, size, false),
        imageUrl: picUrl,
        placeholder: (context, url) =>
            _getPlaceholderOrErrorImage(size, hasBorder),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
            _getPlaceholderOrErrorImage(size, hasBorder));

Widget _getPlaceholderOrErrorImage(double size, hasBorder) => Container(
      width: size,
      height: size,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(size / 2)),
        border: new Border.all(
          color: Colors.white,
          width: hasBorder ? 2.0 : 0.0,
        ),
      ),
      child: ClipOval(
          child: Image.asset(
        'assets/images/placeholder.jpg',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        height: size,
        width: size,
      )),
    );

Widget _getCircularImageProvider(
    ImageProvider provider, double size, bool hasBorder) {
  return Container(
    width: size,
    height: size,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(size / 2)),
      border: new Border.all(
        color: Colors.white,
        width: hasBorder ? 2.0 : 0.0,
      ),
    ),
    child: ClipOval(
        child: FadeInImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            placeholder: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/placeholder.jpg',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: size,
              width: size,
            ).image,
            image: provider)),
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for hideProgress, updateProgress and showProgress?

Comment: @VictorEronmosele i have updated post you can check the helper

Comment: There seems to be an existing issue with `hide` on progress_dialog [here](https://github.com/fayaz07/progress_dialog/issues/64). Can you double check that multiple progress dialogs are not being shown to the user by accident?

Comment: Thank you but this is not the problem :(